# ASP.NET DataGrid annoyance

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

The problem is this, I have a DG which i have it on paging true but when I click the, next page it retrieves the correct records but does not change the selected link. This is like, if I click on page two it gets the page two records but the link stays marked as page 1 I need to click it again to get the 2 blackened.

The code:

```
            read = Con.executar_re(strConsultaPagina);
            DataSet dsPaginas = read;

            dataGridStatusOficio.DataSource = dsPaginas.Tables[0];
            dataGridStatusOficio.DataBind();

            dataGridStatusOficio.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
```

strCo... is the string

```
 "Select Id,DocNum,Note,Date,ReceiverDate,Status,TypeCCompany,Receiver,SigantureDoc,SignaturePosition,Prior,TypeCDocument,InputOutput FROM Oficios_dev2.dbo.doc WHERE DocNum like '%" + txtBuscarNumero.Text.Trim() + "%' and DocNum like '%" + Convert.ToString(Session["Level"]) + "%' "
```

The lines are in the:

```
 protected void dgStatus_changeIndex(object source, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
```

I know is not the most elegant way of doing this, as I'm calling the SQL every time it changes page, but this has a lot of that code that is impossible to not have to get your hands dirty, so can anybody help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you used the PageIndexChanging event?

Comment: The event is OnPageIndexChanged, thats what I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

I would change this..

```
dataGridStatusOficio.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
```

to this

```
dataGridStatusOficio.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
```

and see if this solves your problem. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Nope, there is no PageIndex attribute, only CurrentPageIndex